# bootstrap 4 carousel how to active transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a Bootstrap 4 carousel and I need to move 4 slides each time. I'm using this code, and it works:

```
$(this).carousel(4);
```

The problem is that the carousel just jumps to that index and doesn't show any transitions. If I use `$(this).carousel("next");` or `$(this).carousel("prev");` it works and transitions correctly.

I tried use something like this:

```
$(this).carousel("next");
$(this).carousel("next");
```

But it does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround:

```
test = setInterval(() => {
  count++;
  $(".carousel-control-next").click();
  if (count > 3) {
    count = 0;
    clearInterval(test);
  }
}, 200);
```

I used an interval because the following does not work:

- `$(".carousel-control-next").click()` inside a loop, or
- `$(".carousel-control-next").click()` inside a `setTimeout` inside a loop

Comment: Possibly already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973054/519413.

Comment: Thx for the quickly answer, the client use that library T_T, let see that link now

Comment: What are the class names of these elements, and how are they defined in your CSS? I see no additions of [animation properties](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) in your jQuery code either.

Comment: im not using any custom css, i just want to use the native code of bootstrap, jquery and css to resolve this situation, i even put this code into a loop: $(this).carousel("next") but it does not work T_T

Comment: @BarlyEspinal Is the carousel jumping *instantly* to the target slide with no animations at all? Or is the problem that you get an animation, but it transitions from the current slide to the target slide without showing the intermediate slides?

Comment: @tom the carousel just jump instantly to the target slide with no animations T_T.

Comment: @BarlyEspinal That's odd, I'm not sure why it's doing that. The basic demo in my answer *does* show transitions. If you are happy with your workaround, that's fine; if you want to figure out the root cause, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need to include the required JavaScript and CSS in your project, create the necessary HTML and use build in carousel class.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

link in the "head" and scripts in the end of "body".
Then create the Carousel HTML using the carousel class and a unique IDs. The structure should include indicators, items, and nav controls:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


<!-- Indic-->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img1.jpg" alt="Image 1" width="100%" height="100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Image 1</h3>
        <p>Description 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img2.jpg" alt="Image 2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Image 2</h3>
        <p>Description 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img3.jpg" alt="Image 3" width="100%" height="100%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Image 3</h3>
        <p>Description 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Contr-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Swap "img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", and "img3.jpg" with the your image paths or links (urls) you want to use.
And last thing, activate the carousel, bootstrap automatically activates the it when the `data-ride="carousel"` attribute is added to the main Carousel `div` element.
Also you can check more info here: [carousel bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/).

Hope this helps and answers your question.

Almost forgot:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Initialize the carousel
  $("#myCarousel").carousel({ interval: false });

  // Custom next function
  $(".carousel-control-next").click(function() {
    moveCarousel(4);
  });

  // Custom prev function
  $(".carousel-control-prev").click(function() {
    moveCarousel(-4);
  });

  // Move the carousel by the specified number of slides
  function moveCarousel(steps) {
    var currentIndex = $("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active").index();
    var totalItems = $("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item").length;

    var targetIndex = currentIndex + steps;
    if (targetIndex < 0) {
      targetIndex = 0;
    } else if (targetIndex >= totalItems) {
      targetIndex = totalItems - 1;
    }

    $("#myCarousel").carousel(targetIndex);
  }
});
```

To enable smooth transition effect modify code:

```
// Move the carousel by the specified number of slides
function moveCarousel(steps) {
  var currentIndex = $("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active").index();
  var totalItems = $("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item").length;
  var remainingSteps = steps;

  function moveOneStep() {
    var newIndex = currentIndex + (remainingSteps > 0 ? 1 : -1);
    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= totalItems) {
      return;
    }

    $("#myCarousel").one("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
      remainingSteps -= (remainingSteps > 0 ? 1 : -1);
      if (remainingSteps !== 0) {
        moveOneStep();
      }
    });

    $("#myCarousel").carousel(newIndex);
    currentIndex = newIndex;
  }

  moveOneStep();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `.carousel(4)` doesn't animate for you, it does on a basic example:

```html
<!-- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/#slides-only -->
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active"><svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">First slide</text></svg></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second slide</text></svg></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Third slide</text></svg></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Fourth slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">Fourth slide</text></svg></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Fifth slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Fifth slide</text></svg></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Sixth slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Sixth slide</text></svg></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="$('#carouselExampleSlidesOnly').carousel(4)">Skip to fifth slide</button>

    <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Two notes:

- `.carousel(4)` jumps to the slide at index 4 (i.e. the fifth slide), regardless of the current slide. If you want to jump 4 forward from the current slide, use

  ```
  let index = $(this).find(".active").index();
  $(this).carousel(index + 4);
  ```
- The animation goes directly from the current slide to the target slide, skipping over any intermediate slides. If you want the animation to go through all the intermediate slides, have a look at [@David NoHorizon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76028654/bootstrap-4-carousel-how-to-active-transitions/76029829#76029829).

I noticed that calling `.carousel("next")` twice doesn't work for me either (it only goes forward one slide).